# How to get today added records from database?

Tags: mysql

I have added records in database where as created date is stored in time stamp value means. time() value. But now I want to fetch all records that are added today date. I am stuck and search over google but not found.

```
SELECT  id,COUNT(*) as total,
                   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE( `tsCreated` ) =  CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as todays
                   FROM  products
```

Comment: Hint: `WHERE DATE(tsCreated) = CURDATE()` ... lose that `CASE` expression.

Comment: Not working. I run this SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE DATE(tsCreated) = CURDATE();

Comment: `Not working` ... this query should work AFAIK.  What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,COUNT(*) FROM `products` WHERE DATE(`tsCreated`) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Then maybe you don't have any records from today.  Did you check for that?

Comment: Yes I do have. Its 1493105149 saved in db.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the date if now then 1 else 0:

```
SELECT id,CASE WHEN DATE(`tsCreated`) =  date(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end as todays 
FROM  products
```

if you want to count the tsCreated = Now:

```
SELECT count(1) as total
FROM  products  where DATE(`tsCreated`) =  date(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Kindly show expected output to have you more accurate answers.

Comment: Its just simple output. there are 10-20 rows in table and wana show some of that are created today.

Comment: Yeah you got it.. it's just a simple output because you have just a simple question but you don't know how to show your sample data and expected result.